# I need to access different organizations chatter API and display the feed in our application for logged in users

Tags: chatter, connected-apps

We have an application where users can login with their company email Ids. We have a requirement to display Salesforce Chatter feed in our application for the logged in users.

Once the logged in users in Application authenticate themselves at Salesforce connected app via OAuth, we retrieve the chatter feed via REST Api to display them in our web site.

From my understanding I need to create a connected app in every organization with OAuth enabled to get the chatter feed via REST Api. Practically this is difficult to create a connected app in every organization of our client.

Is there something similar to service account or a global of goolge's in Salesforce?

Any ideas or workarounds on how I can overcome this situation?

Answer (score 0):

One connected app should be enough.

You can use the same clientId and ClientSecret to connect to all of the other orgs.

To know more
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2011/07/quick-tip-using-oauth-across-multiple-orgs.html

Answer (score 0):

It's common misconception that you need connected apps in every instance for your application to function .

Your connected app can be sitting inside a developer edition and all other salesforce instances can use that to do an oauth and authorize .

Alternately your connected application can be packaged .So you may create a connected application and package as unmanaged application or managed  and distribute.
Packaging would allow admin to configure permissions later if needed for various profiles .

Consider an example of workbench app ,the developer of the app would have used a developer edition to create a connected app and workbench can be accessed by any SFDC instance .